# Inno setup скрытая установка

Tags: inno-setup

Есть инсталлер на inno setup. Нужно выполнить тихую установку. Вписываю ключи и всё окей, но в инсталлере был встроен pascal script и 2 дополнительных окна (в CustomMessages секции их видно), эти 2 доп окна нужно подтвердить(да и нет), чтобы установка завершилась успешно полностью. Но тихая установка у inno эти окна обходит и в итоге установка вся не проходит, как положено. Скажите, есть ли способ заставить автоматически программу клацнуть по двум диалогам при тихой установке?

Как при тихой установке изменить по дефолту ответ на окна из секции CM? Или есть ли программа, чтобы запомнила на какие кнопки нажимать и сделала установку тихой?

Answer (score 0):

В документации упоминаются параметры `/SILENT` и `/VERYSILENT`, которые могут комбинироваться с `/SUPPRESSMSGBOXES`. Но при этом есть исключения, в числе которых диалоговые окна, выведенные из pascal script функцией `MsgBox`.

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline

> 5 message boxes are not suppressible:
>
> - The About Setup message box.
> - The Exit Setup? message box.
> - The FileNotInDir2 message box displayed when Setup requires a new disk to be inserted and the disk was not found.
> - Any (error) message box displayed before Setup (or Uninstall) could read the command line parameters.
> - **Any message box displayed by [Code] support function MsgBox.**